# My App is not loaded in Blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry

I am using following code to create xml file -

```
void createxml(){
    Document d = new Document();
    Element root = d.createElement("","company");
    Element employee = d.createElement("","employee");
    employee.setAttribute("","id","1");

    Element fname = d.createElement("","fname");
    fname.addChild(Node.TEXT,"Vasudev");
    Element lname = d.createElement("","lname");
    lname.addChild(Node.TEXT,"Kamath");
    Element address = d.createElement(Node.TEXT+"","address");
    address.addChild(Node.TEXT,"Karkala");

    employee.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,fname);
    employee.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,lname);
    employee.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,address);

    root.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,employee);
    d.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,root);

    String fileName = "file:///SDCard/Blackberry/company.xml";

        DataOutputStream os = null;
        FileConnection fc = null;

        try
        {
               fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileName,Connector.READ_WRITE);
               if (! fc.exists())
                   fc.create();
               os = fc.openDataOutputStream();
               KXmlSerializer serializer = new KXmlSerializer();
               serializer.setOutput(os, "UTF-8");
               d.write(serializer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

But when I write this method, my program is not going to be load on the simulator, if I comment It loads easily. How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Do you get any error message anywhere? What API version do you use and what OS does you simulator have?

Answer (score 0):

Do u simulate your app?
If you running in simulator, create a filder SDCard in your system and then create a sub folder Blackberry. And when you run your app take take the 'Simulate' menu > Change Sd card> Add Directory> and browse for the folder SDcard .... then run you app